# Open Local Notification on tap when Notification received - iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I implemented my local notifications and app shows notification. I have actions under notification like reply, cancel, open app

If app is in background and once user taps on "Open App" I would like to open app

Please let me know how do i handle this i.e., on user tap of notificationAction, open app if it is in background/inactive state

As of now in my didReceive response , I have below code..but it isnt opening app . Pls advice

```
   if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(appHookUpURL! as URL)
               {
                   UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL(appHookUpURL! as URL)
               }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to configure your action as:

```
let openAppAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "YOUR_IDENTIFIER", title: "Open App", options: .foreground)
```

Set the `options` to `.foreground`.

> **UNNotificationActionOptions - foreground**
>
> The action causes the app to launch in the foreground.
>
> When the user selects an action containing this option, the system
>   brings the app to the foreground, asking the user to unlock the device
>   as needed. Use this option for actions that require the user to
>   interact further with your app. Do not use this option simply to bring
>   your app to the foreground.

No need to call `UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL`.

Comment: Sure. Accept and upvote the answer if it worked. Happy coding 